# Default Probability calculation. How to solve system of 2 non linear equations?

Tags: merton-model, nonlinear

I am trying to repeat calculations from Hull(options futures and other derivatives) chapter "Using Equity Prices to Estimate Default Probabilities". I want to solve system of 2 equations:

\begin{cases} 
 E_0 = V_0 N(d_1) - L e^{-rt}N(d_2) \\ 
 \sigma_E E_0 = N(d_1) \sigma_V V_0
\end{cases}
to find $V_0, \sigma_V$, where you recognise Merton model. We assume that other variables are given, hence should be easy to solve numerically system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns. Using matlab ***fsolve*** function, even with feeding analytical Jacobian for different data inputs sometimes returns me:

**No solutions found.**
or
**Equation solved, fsolve stalled.**

This is even worse if I use Black Cox model, as the 1st equation(barrier option) and 2nd equation(because of $\frac{\partial E }{\partial V}$ term) is getting huge.

Could somebody give some hint how to solve this system?

Could somebody give tips or ideas how to choose good initial conditions for ***fsolve***? 
( Finally, I eager to be able to solve Black Cox model)

**Update:** I have been thinking to search for reference how to work with ill-posed problems, or trying to identify if condition number is good, but I can not do the last as the system is non linear( I can not represent it as a matrix).

Comment: Why is $V_0$ unknown? Isn't that the total value of the firm's assets?

Comment: Exactly. I think that it is not observable, but as initial condition for $V_0$ I do the following approximation for it's value: $$V_0 = \sum  \# \text{ outstanding stocks}_0\times \text{price of a stock}_0 + \text{short and long term debts}_0
$$

Comment: Could you post your matlab code as well? I can take a look.

Comment: You will have to use numerical methods since the inverse function of the Gaussian integral, $\mathcal{N}^{-1}[x]}$, is not analytically invertible. It’s analogous to solving for implied volatility of an option... you must approximate and/or iteratively converge.

Answer (score -1):

> Could somebody give some hint how to solve this system?

I am not a Matlab user but I know that people tend to use the `nleqslv` package in `R`. See e.g., [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Loop-and-Solver-with-Black-Scholes-Formula-td3470488.html). This implementation or the defaults in the method may help you.

You can also consider the iterative method or maximum likelihood if you have a series of data. I have implemented it in [this `R` package](https://github.com/boennecd/DtD) .